# How to increase a variable value and use it for the same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make this code works, I am using jQuery and HTML, the goal is to show a content (web page) on a kind of slide show (change page by clicking next button). so here is what I coded so far thinking that it will work. The problem is that when I click next for the first time it shows the 2nd content (easy because the value is defined in the beginning) but when i click for the 2nd time it doesn't work! the problem is that the function is not using the increased value of the variable `content`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var content;
            content = 2;
            var mid;
            mid = "." + content;
            prevC = content - 1;
            midpC = "." + prevC;
            jQuery('.button_1').click(function(){
                jQuery(mid).fadeIn('slow');
                jQuery(midpC).fadeOut('fast');
                content++;
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div class="1">
        <div dir="rtl" style="text-align: right;" trbidi="on">
            <div style="text-align: left;">
                TEST CONT. 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /></div>
    <div class="2" style="display: none;">TEST CONT. 2</div>
    <div class="3" style="display: none;">TEST CONT. 3</div>
    <div class="post-pagination"></div>
    <a class="button_1" href="#">Next</a>
    <br />
    <span style="background-color: #990000;"><br /></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `mid` and `midpc` were set outside the `click` function, So every time you click the button you just change `content` but `mid` and `midpc` remain still. You should update `mid` and `midpc` after `content++`.

---

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var current = 1;
  // Next
  jQuery('.button_1').click(function(){
    jQuery('.' + current).fadeOut('fast');
    current = current % 3 + 1;
    jQuery('.' + current).fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });
  // Previous
  jQuery('.button_2').click(function () {
    jQuery('.' + current).fadeOut('fast');
    current--;
    if (current < 1) current = 3;
    jQuery('.' + current).fadeIn('slow');
  })
});
```

Comment: It should be `current = (current + 1) % 3` and it should be before the second line so you won't caluclate it twice.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The classes are from 1 to 3, but you will get `0` if you write `current = (current + 1) % 3`.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i still need to update the prevC... anyway the problem is solved as i found out the mistak i made. thanks again

Comment: Oh problem solved 100%! thank you hsfzxjy
Can you please tell me what should i change now to make do previous page ? (it will take me 3 hours to make it)

Comment: Can you please tell me what should i change now to make do previous page ? (it will take me 3 hours to make it)

Comment: Honestly, while this works, you really should just avoid the global variable altogether ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do what you need. Note that this allows the user to move forward or backward but if you dont want backward, just remove that button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.change-slide').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // avoid navigation since your buttons are acutally links
    var $this = $(this); // cache "this"
    var $slides = $('.slide'); // get all the slides
    var isNext = $this.hasClass('next'); // check if the clicked button was "next" or "previous"
    var currentSlideIndex = $this.data('current-slide');  // get the current slide index from the button
    var newSlideIndex = isNext ? currentSlideIndex+1 : currentSlideIndex-1; // subtract or add 1 as needed 
    if (newSlideIndex >= $slides.length) newSlideIndex = 0; // reset to begining when reaching the end
    if (newSlideIndex < 0) newSlideIndex = $slides.length - 1; // reset to end when reaching the begining 
    $('.change-slide').data('current-slide', newSlideIndex); // set the current val to all buttons to use later 
    $slides.fadeOut('fast'); // fade out all slides 
    $slides.eq(newSlideIndex).fadeIn('slow'); // fade in the current slide
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="slide">
  <div dir="rtl" style="text-align: right;" trbidi="on">
    <div style="text-align: left;">
      TEST CONT. 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
<div class="slide" style="display: none;">TEST CONT. 2</div>
<div class="slide" style="display: none;">TEST CONT. 3</div>
<div class="post-pagination"></div>
<a class="button_1 change-slide previous" href="#" data-current-slide="0">Previous</a>
<a class="button_1 change-slide next" href="#" data-current-slide="0">Next</a>
<br />
<span style="background-color: #990000;"><br /></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking next button is only incrementing the variable `content` but the class selector used in the jquery function `mid` and `midpC` remain unchanged.

The correct way is to update the selectors `mid` and `midpC` after incrementing the variable `content`.

---

Here is the modified code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var content;
        content = 2;
        var mid;
        jQuery('.button_1').click(function(){
            // notice following code is now inside the click function
            mid = "." + content;
            prevC = content - 1;
            midpC = "." + prevC;
            jQuery(mid).fadeIn('slow');
            jQuery(midpC).fadeOut('fast');
            content++;
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="1">
    <div dir="rtl" style="text-align: right;" trbidi="on">
        <div style="text-align: left;">
            TEST CONT. 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /></div>
<div class="2" style="display: none;">TEST CONT. 2</div>
<div class="3" style="display: none;">TEST CONT. 3</div>
<div class="post-pagination"></div>
<a class="button_1" href="#">Next</a>
<br />
<span style="background-color: #990000;"><br /></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

My gut says this is an issue with a closure.  Sounds like the result of clicking "next" is assigned one time at the beginning, as "go to page 2."  Then, when you click again, it's still "go to page 2."